# How can I put "various" instance of click Listener on Google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps

[EXAMPLE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrnek.jpg)

I put many circles on the map, and I wish to these circles have their own OncircleClick Listener

but the problem is, I can regist only one circle click listener on the googleMap, and This Listener is shared by every circle, so every Times I click any circles, same listener event would occured.

Could you let me know how to make each circles can have their own On circle click Listener? thank you.

here is my tried code :

```
 private void drawCircle(LatLng point, boolean isOverThreshold, final Bundle results){

        GoogleMap.OnCircleClickListener onCircleClickListener = new GoogleMap.OnCircleClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCircleClick(Circle circle) {

                int sixty_one = results.getInt("60hz_1");
                int eighty_one = results.getInt("180hz_1");
                int sixty_two = results.getInt("60hz_2");
                int eighty_two = results.getInt("180hz_2");
                int sixty_three = results.getInt("60hz_3");
                int eighty_three = results.getInt("180hz_3");
                double speed = results.getDouble("speed");
                Toast.makeText(ReplayActivity.this, "CH1: ("+sixty_one+","+eighty_one+") \n"+" CH2: (" + sixty_two+","+eighty_two+") \n" + "CH3: ("+sixty_three+","+eighty_three+")\n speed:"+speed+"m/s )",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Log.d("gd","circle clicked!");
            }
        };

        // Instantiating CircleOptions to draw a circle around the marker
        CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions();

        // Specifying the center of the circle
        circleOptions.center(point);

        (....)


        // Adding the circle to the GoogleMap
        map.addCircle(circleOptions);
        map.setOnCircleClickListener(onCircleClickListener); 
//but this oncircleListener is shared by every circle click event..
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Circle.setTag()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)) method of created circle object to set, for example the ID of Circle object (or more complex structure) as Tag, and then use [`Circle.getTag()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle.html#getTag()) inside yours `onCircleClickListener` to get this ID (or more complex structure). Something like that:

```
private void drawCircle(LatLng point, boolean isOverThreshold, final Bundle results){

    GoogleMap.OnCircleClickListener onCircleClickListener = new GoogleMap.OnCircleClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCircleClick(Circle circle) {

            // get stored Tag object from passed circle object
            YOUR_TAG_OBJECT_CLASS yourTagObjectName = (YOUR_TAG_OBJECT_CLASS)circle.getTag();
            if (yourTagObjectName != null) {
                // parse it
                switch (yourTagObjectName.id) {
                    case ID_1: ... break;
                    case ID_2: ... break; 
                    ...
                }
             }

            int sixty_one = results.getInt("60hz_1");
            int eighty_one = results.getInt("180hz_1");
            int sixty_two = results.getInt("60hz_2");
            int eighty_two = results.getInt("180hz_2");
            int sixty_three = results.getInt("60hz_3");
            int eighty_three = results.getInt("180hz_3");
            double speed = results.getDouble("speed");
            Toast.makeText(ReplayActivity.this, "CH1: ("+sixty_one+","+eighty_one+") \n"+" CH2: (" + sixty_two+","+eighty_two+") \n" + "CH3: ("+sixty_three+","+eighty_three+")\n speed:"+speed+"m/s )",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Log.d("gd","circle clicked!");
        }
    };

    // Instantiating CircleOptions to draw a circle around the marker
    CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions();

    // Specifying the center of the circle
    circleOptions.center(point);

    (....)


    // Adding the circle to the GoogleMap
    Circle circle = map.addCircle(circleOptions);  // <- store circle object
    circle.setTag(YOUR_TAG_ID_OR_OBJECT);          // <- set Tag to stored circle object

    map.setOnCircleClickListener(onCircleClickListener); 
}
```